# Providing built-in types like String in Angular using useClass

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Consider the following provider:

```
{provide: String, useClass: String}
```

What I think happens is angular simply tries to create an object of the class mentioned as value of **useClass** property. It analyses the constructor, checks if it needs to resolve it's dependencies, injects them and creates the object. The String class does have a constructor with no parameters which returns an empty string. Hence the above provider should work and an empty string should be injected. But I get the following error:
[image]

I have 2 questions:

1. Why do I get this error when Angular should be able to instantiate a String object.
2. I thought that DI system tries to instantiate the dependencies only when they are first injected. I get this error even if I don't inject and just provide.

I thought maybe it's because of the @Injectable decorator. Because String class will not have it, but I created a service without this decorator, provided and injected it and everything works fine. Also I know there are other ways of providing an empty string, I was just playing around, came across this error. Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For undecorated classes, the `R3Injector` is checking the number of parameters for the class and throws if it's more than `0`.

```
function getUndecoratedInjectableFactory(token: Function) {
  // If the token has parameters then it has dependencies that we cannot resolve implicitly.
  const paramLength = token.length;
  if (paramLength > 0) {
    const args: string[] = newArray(paramLength, '?');
    throw new RuntimeError(
        RuntimeErrorCode.INVALID_INJECTION_TOKEN,
        ngDevMode && `Can't resolve all parameters for ${stringify(token)}: (${args.join(', ')}).`);
  }
  ...
}
```

[See source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5212b47bbf9f3da890176512296a49c1b98263c8/packages/core/src/di/r3_injector.ts#L480-L488).

In our case, `String.length` return `1` thus the error raised.

If you want to provide built-in types, use `useFactory` :
`{provide: String, useFactory: () => new String()}`

### This way, the DI system doesn't have the resolve the arguments of the string constructor.

Edit:
For you 2nd question, the exception is raised even without injection because it's the code creating the provider factories that throws. At boostrap, Angular creates factories for every providers. These factories are then called when injecting the classes.

Comment: But the String constructor does not have any arguments. I can use "new String( )" without any error. I know the other methods like useFactory or useValue. I mentioned it in my question.

Comment: Please see my edit, it's because the token throws if the length > 0. `String.length` return `1`.

Comment: 2nd edit with the angular source code which explains the behavior.

Comment: okay thanks I got the answer to question 1. But what about question 2.

Comment: I've edited my answser. I hope it answers your question !